# Zend add base url to all links in content

Tags: zend-framework, codeigniter, autolink

I want to add the base_url to all internal links in blocks of text in my views, to help prevent content-scraping. My idea was to use something like a good equivalent of CodeIgniter's auto_link() helper for Zend Framework. Does it exist?

Answer (score 2):

You should do that anyways. Use the [baseUrl view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl).

```
<img src="<?= $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/image.png" />
```

or

```
<img src="<?= $this->baseUrl('/images/image.png'); ?>" />
```

or

```
<img src="<?= $this->baseUrl() . '/images/image.png'; ?>" />
```